# Calculate interest of late payment (using different percent for multiple time ranges)

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

I need to calculate interest of late payment. Problem is that in Poland its called statutory interest and it changes overtime (so percent if different to multilpe date ranges). To simplify calculation we can agree that each year is 365 days long.

So, because there many different rates, I've to store them somehow, so I have:

```
STATUTORY_INTEREST_PERCENT = [
    {
        'start': '09.10.2014',
        # no end value, as its current (so use today date)
        'percent': 8
    },
    {
        'start': '04.07.2013',
        'end': '08.10.2014',
        'percent': 10
    },
    {
        'start': '06.06.2013',
        'end': '03.07.2013',
        'percent': 10.5
    },
    {
        'start': '09.05.2013',
        'end': '05.06.2013',
        'percent': 11
    },
    {
        'start': '07.03.2013',
        'end': '08.05.2013',
        'percent': 11.5
    },
    {
        'start': '07.02.2013',
        'end': '06.03.2013',
        'percent': 12.5
    },
    # stripped many values as there many of them back to 1989...
]
```

Now, for a given date (payment deadline) and amount I need to calculate value of interest as for today (current date).

For example, for payment deadline date 06.01.2019 and amount 2000 it should calculate:

06.01.2019, 04.06.2019, 150,    8,00% -> 65,75

(deadline date, current date, days count, interest rate used for detected ranges)

So it is simple (one range).

But for date payment deadline rate like 03.06.2013, it should use more ranges, so calculation should be like:

```
09.10.2014, 04.06.2019, 1700,   8,00%,  745,21

04.07.2013, 08.10.2014, 462,    10,00%, 253,15

06.06.2013, 03.07.2013, 28,     10,50%, 16,11

03.06.2013, 05.06.2013, 3,      11,00%, 1,81
```

So total interest amount which should be calculated is 1016,28

Any ideas how to calculate it quickly in Python?